# Can we model multiple inheritance with Grakn?

Tags: rdf, owl, rdfs, vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

In RDF/OWL we can have a class with many superclasses either assigned or inferred through multiple inheritance. Many reference ontologies require the support of multiple inheritance.

However, Grakn only supports single type inheritance, how to use Grakn for this.

For example, can this example be modelled in Grakn?

```
company      rdf:type         rdfs:Class
government   rdf:type         rdfs:Class

employer     rdf:type         rdfs:Class
employer     rdfs:subClassOf  government
employer     rdfs:subClassOf  government
```

Answer (score 0):

The example posted in the question models an `employer` as both of class `company` and `government`. However, although this may look correct, the problem is that often multiple inheritance, as a modelling concept, is not used in the right way. Multiple inheritance should group things, and not subclass "types", where each type is a definition of something else. In other words, we don't want to represent instances of data. This is a common mistake.

Instead of multiple inheritance, we should assign roles, which allow us to model any type of domain. A role defines the behaviour and aspect of a thing in the context of a relation, and we can assign multiple roles to a thing (note that roles are inherited when types subclass another).

For example, a `government` can employ a `person`, and a `company` can employ a `person`. One might suggest to then create a class that inherits both `government` and `company` which can employ a `person`, and end up with an `employer` class that subclasses both (as shown in the example above).

However, this is an abuse of inheritance. In this case, we should create a role `employer`, which relates to an `employment` relation and contextualises how a `company` or `government` is involved in that relation (by playing the role of `employer`).

```
company sub entity,
    plays employer;

government sub entity,
    plays employer;

employment sub relation,
    relates employer;
```